# PyFlink module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, pyflink

I want to run simple example from Flink documentation.
And after start i got exception:

```
 Unable to make field private final byte[] java.lang.String.value accessible:
 module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @228575c0
```

Installed:

```
Python 3.10.6

openjdk version "19.0.2" 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 19.0.2+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu322.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.2+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu322.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Simple code from flink site:

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/python/examples/datastream/word_count.html

Comment: I cannot for the life of me understand why Flink feels it necessary to hack the String class.

Comment: I do not fully understand why on a clean system, in the first article for beginners, I get problems. I have very good first impressions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flink doesn't support JDK 19, only 8 and 11.